# How to see interpreted/translated code in R?

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and I'm trying to better understand how R works under the hood.  Often times, I'll get an error that shows syntax that wasn't even in my code.  I know there must be a lot of translation going on under the hood.  Is there an easy way to see what code is actually executing for a line of code.

For some context, I was using stringr

```
filterStatement = Orders$clean %like% currow$clean & (Orders$zip5==currow$MailingZip5 | Orders$zip5.1==currow$MailingZip5)
```

and got this error:

```
Error in grepl(pattern, vector, ignore.case = ignore.case, fixed = fixed) : 
  invalid regular expression 'XXXX (XXXXXX', reason 'Missing ')''
```

I figured out that %like% is a wrappr for grep but is there a better way to see that when I type

```
Orders$clean %like% currow$clean
```

it's getting converted to

```
grepl(currow$clean, Orders$clean, ignore.case = FALSE, fixed = FALSE)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes viewing source code can help. For example, `%in%` is a syntactic sugar for a function based on `match`. You can use `View(\`%in%\`)` to see what is going on behind the scene.

Comment: You can start by looking into the documentation for packages that you are using. Calling `?grepl` will show you the required and optional parameters associated with a function. Frequently you can find the exactly specifics in a package's github repository.